# AMD Quad-Core A10-8700P vs Intel Core i7 5500U

Tags: laptop, processor, development

I didn't use any AMD processor before, so things getting confusing for me. Someone is going to gift me a laptop. It has an AMD A10 processor  [here is the full specification](http://www.91mobiles.com/dell-15-5555-x560583in9-amd-quad-core-a10-8-gb-1-tb-windows-8-1-laptop-price-in-india-81917)

I am a developer, I have to use software like NetBeans and Android Studio simultaneously. So my question is will this laptop fulfill my requirements? Or should I ask a different one which has Intel Core i7 processor inside, something like [this laptop](http://www.ryanscomputers.com/Dell-Inspiro-7952)?

If the first laptop (AMD processor inside) is enough for my workload, then I won't tell him to change  otherwise I have to tell him to change the laptop. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The A10 laptop is enough for you. In reality, the two laptops are very similar except the Intel one may run a little faster and produce less heat and have longer battery life. For programming and normal day to day tasks, the A10 is plenty enough.

Comment: be sure to check your RAM capacity, I recommend 8 GB min pref 12.

Comment: @Thomcdrom They both have 8GB of RAM

Answer (score 1):

They're not all that different.

A rough estimate of relative CPU computational power: http://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp%5B%5D=2542&cmp%5B%5D=2470

(note the 35W AMD TDP vs the 15W Intel TDP; this is what Mr. Zhu was referring to when he estimated the Intel would have better battery life given identical batteries, HDDs, etc.)

The AMD chip will enjoy somewhat better GPU performance: http://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-Radeon-R6-Carrizo-Benchmarks.144290.0.html

Especially if you upgrade the system RAM from 1600mhz to something more like 2133mhz sodimms (example product: [http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231751&nm_mc=AFC-C8Junction&cm_mmc=AFC-C8Junction-PCPartPicker,%20LLC-*-na-*-na-_-na&cm_sp=&AID=10446076&PID=3938566&SID=](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231751&nm_mc=AFC-C8Junction&cm_mmc=AFC-C8Junction-PCPartPicker,%20LLC-_-na-_-na-_-na&cm_sp=&AID=10446076&PID=3938566&SID=))

I would say that if mobility is a big concern, then ask for an Intel model. Also ask for Intel if you absolutely, positively MUST have the best single-thread performance.

Otherwise, if you're usually going to be plugged in wherever you work, and you are looking for a more well-rounded processor in your laptop, get the A10-8700P and upgrade its RAM.